# apt-get fails to resolve url in docker container, even though the container can resolve it just fine!

Tags: debian, docker, apt

This is such a strange situation.
I'm trying to build an image, and `apt-get update` fails.
Network works fine though. DNS is fine, I can even wget the same urls just fine!!

See terminal output :

```
❯ docker run -i -t python /bin/bash

root@e0264555b919:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

root@e0264555b919:/# wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease
--2023-01-07 11:50:33--  http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease
Resolving deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)... 151.101.62.132, 2a04:4e42:f::644
Connecting to deb.debian.org (deb.debian.org)|151.101.62.132|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 44066 (43K)
Saving to: ‘InRelease’

InRelease                   100%[==========================================>]  43.03K  --.-KB/s    in 0.01s

2023-01-07 11:50:33 (3.84 MB/s) - ‘InRelease’ saved [44066/44066]

root@e0264555b919:/# head InRelease
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

Origin: Debian
Label: Debian
Suite: stable-updates
Version: 11-updates
Codename: bullseye-updates
Date: Sat, 07 Jan 2023 08:40:57 UTC
Valid-Until: Sat, 14 Jan 2023 08:40:57 UTC

root@e0264555b919:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1

root@e0264555b919:/#
```

Any idea on why it does that? I tried several debian based images, all the same issue!

Comment: it might be the permissions to /etc/resolv.conf. I can see it has an owner of 1000 when the root user has id 0. It obviously mounts the one I have in my host. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41229 
But I cannot see why that makes apt/apt-get fail. wget works, curl works... Also apk on alpine images works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was that the docker root directory was in an ntfs partition with user ownership ( not root ).

I moved it because `/` was running out of space, and it seems like the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is mounted on all containers.
apt-get didn't like that for some reason and cannot read it.

I re-installed docker with `/var/lib/docker` as the default root directory, and debian containers work fine now.

So, I guess I need a root owned partition to be able to move the docker root directory.

Answer (score -1):

This errors after type "apt-get update" looks like have not outside access. Try to test it by e.g. curl -I https://google.com
or just
ping google.com

Comment: Exactly, that is what I'm saying. It looks like access, but it's not!

The curl command you gave me, works fine in that same container! But apt-get doesn't.

Read the terminal output I pasted, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Do you try use sudo? I know its root.

Comment: cannot do that. 

❯ docker run -i -t python /bin/bash
root@0d4f07365963:/# sudo apt-get update
bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: In my opinion the sudo is the clue but Im not sure. Read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/440118/why-does-apt-get-require-sudo I have a sudo pkg on each my VM's. Type dpkg -l and check.

Comment: @marlon You use sudo to run it as root. Docker containers doesn't really have anything but root, and `sudo` is *not* the clue. Lack of privileges would not lead to this error message anyway; try it yourself - run `apt update` as normal user.

Comment: Maybe permissions to resources directory at etc/apt-get ? But it no make sense for user root.

Comment: See @vidarlo, the permissions in this case has been the solution.

Comment: @marlon I'd argue the issue likely was NTFS...

Comment: @vidarlo, and I'd argue the issue likely was permissions :-) I met this in VE systems, so I  thought the sudo was reason.